# ReactJS: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error, reactjs

For some reason I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`. No matter how simple the code is, I keep getting this error. There are similar questions but none solve this issue.

```js
var Example = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <h1> Hello </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render( <Example/> , document.getElementById('example'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="example"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention it says the syntax error is on line 1, which is `render: function()`

Comment: Your example works, given React environment: [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/)

Comment: What is with the extra whitespace?

Comment: @epascarello I think it added the extra space when I used tidy.

Comment: @Amadan Yeah, it works on online editors.

Comment: line 1 is not `render: function()` maybe you have some weird character set on.. can you show the whole code?

Comment: This is not best practice `< h1 > Hello < /h1>` remove extra white-space between tag name `<h1> Hello </h1>`

Comment: @TIJ i know is not best practice, stack overflow editor added the white space.
@webdeb  Atom was compiling my jsx file to js. In the js file `render: function()` was the first line, it was compiling it in a weird syntax. I solved it by removing the jsx compiler package from atom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is JSX syntax, you need to include the 'jsx transformer'.
Base on Facebook's recommendation, you should use babeljs, https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/

Comment: I found the problem. I had an atom package that was compiling my jsx file to js. Thank you for the help

Comment: What package was that?

Comment: @corasan it's no longer available

Comment: @Kalanamith what is no longer available?

Comment: @corasan the link you have provided in the answer . please update

Comment: It wasn't me who posted it